# When you have read this page / When you read this page

Tags: present-tense

I have the following sentence in my grammar book:

> **When you have read** this page, turn over and read the other side.

I have known before it that we use present time with a construction "When...." for future actions. I understand that Present Perfect also is present time, but I guess we could use here also Present Simple. Right?

> **When you read** this page, turn over and read the other side.

So, Present Perfect is used here only to amplify the work done. But I can use here also Present Simple if I need to describe the process of doing. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that wouldn't be right. "When you read this page" means "While you are reading this page". You might say for example:

> When you read this page, take notes to make sure you understand.

But you can't use it to mean "when you have finished reading".